# Object in Template Literals vs. Outside

Tags: javascript, template-literals

I recently started using [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in my code, and to my understanding,

```
"Text: " + variable
```

is the exact same as

```
`Text: ${variable}`
```

(In this case, I expected `variable` to be the same as `` `${variable}` ``)

It seems to work with everything **but** objects. For example, the snippet below outputs the correct object.

```js
var obj = {"text": "more text"};

console.log(obj);
```

Whereas this snippet only outputs `[object Object]`. Why does this do that?

```js
var obj = {"text": "more text"};

console.log(`${obj}`);
```

From what I know, the only way around that is to specifically select the key by doing

```
console.log(`${obj.text}`);
```

Except, if I want to see the whole object, how can I do that?

### **TL;DR:** When using objects, template literals don't seem to work the way they should. Why do they do that and is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```js
const obj = {a:1,b:2}

console.log(`${JSON.stringify(obj)}`)
```

When an object is tried to be concat by using `+` or interpolated in a `string` it first converts object to string by calling `Object.prototype.toString()`. And it doesnot return real object.What it return is below.

```js
console.log({a:1,b:2}.toString())
```